How to pass an "%" wildcard to LIKE CONCAT operator using PgPreparedStatement
I need to create a sql using PgPreparedStatement(postgres) query which has like concat operator. The query looks similar to this:
Select * from guest gg where 
gg.city LIKE CONCAT('PHOENI_' , '%');

This looks pretty easy but the sql query is created using some Custom classes and so when
pstmt.setString(1, x); // dummy value 1

then the value of x here is includes '%' and the query is not formed properly. Below are the variations I have used in 'x' and corresponding query formed:

What I see is that if the target string does not have any single quotes , then PreparedStatement would add single quotes around the target String(case 1 of the image), but if I add single quotes anywhere inside the target string, then PreparedStatement would add single quote before every single quote encountered.
I have tried the solution presented here: Using "like" wildcard in prepared statement but still the same result.
The issue I think is that the string value that PreparedStatement would use to replace the marker will always have the "%" (thats how the classes are designed. these are very old and cannot be atleast for changed now). Basically, I cannot do something like this:
Select * from guest gg where gg.city LIKE CONCAT(? , '%');
pstmt.setString(1, "xyz"); // the string that will be used to replace the marker will either have "%" or not.

So, with these limitations, is there a way to have the query as
Select * from guest gg where 
    gg.city LIKE CONCAT('PHOENI_' , '%');

Thanks in advance!
Edit 1:
The query is formed using a custom class(CreateCriteria). This class has 3 parameters:

type(the data type that will be replacing '?')
operator( LIKE CONCAT , LIKE , etc)
value(the value to replace '?')

As far as PreparedStatement is concerned, it is created using Connection object and the sql query.
this.pstmt = m_con.prepareStatement(qry.toString());

The issue here is that for LIKE CONCAT to work, I need to pass '%' but how the class is designed, the value that replaces placeholder is always with '%' and so preparedstatement treats it as a single string value. ( examples are presented in the screenshot).

Please show the prepared statement that the legacy code will create. I am assuming it looks like Select * from guest gg where  gg.city LIKE CONCAT(?); but I cant be sure. Also maybe you can show how the prepared statement is created? maybe you can inherit from the legacy code and override it.

@BIBOOunit question is updated.

if you have an option between LIKE CONCAT and LIKE, can you perform the concat within your java code then use LIKE?

This is a reasonable solution and it works. Makes me wonder why I couldn’t think of it. Thanks a lot!
